# Gmail API: rfc822msgid query not working for some third party domains

Tags: gmail-api

It seems that using rfc822msgid in a messages.list query does not work for some emails originated in third party domains.

eg, this works: "rfc822msgid:XYZ@mail.gmail.com"

but this doesn't: "rfc822msgid:ABC@blah.com" even tho this email is in my inbox...

What would make this query return empty results even tho the messages are in the inbox?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think `rfc822msgid:<1235@mail.domain.com>` should work for other domains. Does it work in the regular gmail client?

Comment: Turns out it works for most third party domain cases, but somehow the examples I picked repeatedly do not work... what would make a particular domain's message-id's not searchable?

Comment: That's odd. The only thing I can think of is that the value might contain some characters that are not allowed. It is best to url-encode the string before using it: `<123@slack-job-worker.somestrangedomain.com>` => `%3C123%40slack-job-worker.somestrangedomain.com%3E`

Comment: Can confirm this for @facebookmail.com.